# Firebase Google Sign In exception. Internal error : Request to API blocked

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-oauth, google-cloud-firestore, google-signin

Here's the error thrown while calling the signInWithCredential function of firebaseAuth.

```
    W/exception: com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ Requests to this API identitytoolkit method google.firebase.auth.v1.IdentityIdaasAuthenticationService.SignInWithIdp are blocked. ]
                                                           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzce.zzb(Unknown Source:55)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzbb.zza(Unknown Source:42)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzcy.zzc(Unknown Source:11)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzdb.onFailure(Unknown Source:35)
                                                           at com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzci.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source:83)
                                                           at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source:22)
                                                           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:697)
```

Google sign-in is complete though (obviously) and I have received the IDToken.
Faced this while following the official firebase google sign in documentation.

NOTE: I might have mistakenly disabled a cloud api service while fooling around. Though the identitytoolkit is enabled in the cloud api, I don't know if there are some sort of rules to it that I can apply

Comment: how you solved this